# add a tag to end of files' filenames within subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, rename

Trying to create a batch file in Windows to add a "Scanned" tag to the filename of multiple PDF files that are each within their own subfolder. I currently have this code but it does not successfully rename the PDF files within any of the subfolders. I'm not sure why it doesn't work; it only seems to be able to rename files in the same directory I have the batch file in.

I should note that I was able to get it working perfectly just once, but I don't remember what I changed that got it to work and unfortunately didn't save it.

```
for /r %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    ren "%%~nf%%~xf" "%%~nf Scanned%%~xf"
)
```

Comment: Will this give you what you need, `Ren "%%f" "%%~nf Scanned%%~xf"`? Also we have no idea if your script is in the working directory or not, meaning that you may wish to specifically include your base search directory after `/r`, i.e. `For /R "X:\MyPath\BaseDir" %%f in…`

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you very much. Can I ask what was it about my original code that was making it not work? And yes, the script is in the working directory.

Comment: Yes, the `ren`ame command you were using differed from the one I provided in my comment!